# AXIS 2 : java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.dom.DeferredElementNSImpl cannot be cast to org.apache.axiom.om.OMElement

Tags: soap, apache-axis

I am using AXIS2 as client for handling SOAP response. The client stubs are generated using WSDL2JAVA command. To solve an issue, I am trying to read an xml response stored in .xml file in the generated stub, and assign to SOAPEnvelope. Below is the code written to load .xml content :

```
InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream((sb.toString()).getBytes());
javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory factory = avax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    factory.setNamespaceAware(true);
    javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder builder = null;
    builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
    org.w3c.dom.Document doc = builder.parse(is);
    System.out.println("Got Document ..............");
    is.close();
org.apache.axis2.saaj.util.SAAJUtil su = new org.apache.axis2.saaj.util.SAAJUtil();
org.apache.axiom.soap.SOAPEnvelope _returnEnv1 = su.getSOAPEnvelopeFromDOOMDocument(doc);
```

Am getting ClassCastException at the last line in the code (assigning to SOAPEnvelope).
Can someone please help me with this.

Answer (score 0):

Axis2clients are used to send requests and receive response. Why are you trying to load response from a file? You should receive the response from the backend service. Check this guide to get to know about the [clientapi](http://wso2.org/library/290). You can find detail guide in axis2 documentation also.

Comment: Thanks for your response...I do get response from backend service, and will save the response in xml file. The data I receive will not not be same the next day (records get updated every night).I am saving the data to a file so that I can test and verify if therez any wrong data ...and fix any issue raised.most of the issues are reproduceble..But I have a issue which is not easy to reproduce..So thought of using the saved SOAP response in xml and reproduce and fix the issue...Please let me know if there is any other way to access saved data and assign it to SOAPEnvelope.